# Obfuscating autoincrement DB id, using mathematical function

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications, primary-key, obfuscation

I have auto-increment ids as primary is all of my db tables, like users, orders etc. I do not want to expose these ids to end users, as they may iterate over IDs can get access to user details. Instead I want to use a 2-way maths function such that I can obfuscate and de-obfuscate an id without storing a DB mapping.

```
function obfuscate(id)
{
    constSeed = 1203793
    return (id*constSeed)
}

function deobfuscate(bigid)
{
    constSeed = 1203793
    return (bigid/constSeed)
}
```

I can even run the bigid through a base36 converter, to get a smaller alphanumeric id, publicly exposable.

Are issues with this approach? Any other suggestions?

Comment: You could just not use auto_increment and generate the id in a controlled-random manner. (If it can be predicted what kind of numbers you are obfuscating, it could make it easier to deobfuscate them or guess valid obfuscation values.) ...although, knowing an id should not be a primary security concern...users should not have the kind of access necessary to take advantage of such knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want them with access to the ID's maybe use them only in $_SESSION variables or something along those lines.

If the data is visible to the end user, even if you hash or encrypt the data,
it will not be safe.